# Cómo accedo a la propiedad de un objeto cuando su nombre es un número?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Este es mi objeto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi codigo es este:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>gana</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="values in juegosYlogros" :key="values.id">
            <td>{{values.id}}</td>
            <td>{{values.ganajuego.0.odds}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: prueba del error]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que esta pregunta no es igual a esta que publicaste hace uno minutos? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/226398/quero-acceder-a-la-propiedad-de-un-objeto-que-es-un-numero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La propiedad `ganajuego` es de tipo `array` por lo que para acceder a la "propiedad" `0` (en realidad es una posición, no una propiedad) deberías hacerlo con la notación de corchetes de esta forma: `values.ganajuego[0].odds`